# How to combine branch in git?

Tags: git, branch

I used "git push origin master" but git upload the code into  "https://bitbucket.org/username/stm32f4/src/2f863e25b31798103a498a8eafcaa3a66f70fbd3/" this address. When I look the original git address which always I use, there is no changes! How can I upload to code into my original git address which is "https://bitbucket.org/username/stm32f4/src/master/", this address?
 Note: I can not combine branch. Also I do not want to use branch. I probably opened the branch by mistake, and suddenly I am loading the codes in there. When I click on the "Branch" tab and want to delete it, I get the warning "You can not delete the master branch". Do you have any suggestion?

edit: I added screenshot

[After upload there is no change in master](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSNix.jpg)

[Strange address that I have uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nM6Ag.jpg)

edit2: added second screenshot;
[branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv9ab.jpg)

Comment: Hi @discoverer, I have difficulties understanding what's your situation and what you want to do. Also are you using a graphical git client?

Comment: Hi @ErniBrown. I use git bash terminal. I want to use "git push origin master" command to upload my code into bitbucket account. But after upload to code processing, I can see new commit in my bitbucket account but like this "https://bitbucket.org/username/stm32f4/src/2f863e25b31798103a498a8eafcaa3a66f70fbd3/". Normally I should to see like this; "https://bitbucket.org/username/stm32f4/src/master". I'll share photos about the issue.

Comment: Still not sure what's wrong, what I can tell you is: master is a ref to the final commit you did on `master` branch. `2f863e25b31798103a498a8eafcaa3a66f70fbd3` is one of the commit you did sometimes, not sure when.

If you have a terminal I suggest you to check commits history with `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`, or with a graphical tool like gitk, smartgit, gitkraken, gitextension...
This way you should be able to understand when was the commit made, and how to recover to that commit

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there was no problem. Interestingly, when I look at the chrome browser on my own google account, the problem is happening. But the problem was solved when I use the chrome browser incognito mode or when I used another browser. Even though I could not understand why, after a few days, the problem  is solved .